# NetBeans HTML Code Hinting/Completion for Attributes

Tags: html, netbeans, code-completion, code-hinting

Has anyone had success with getting NetBeans to display code hinting/completes for html *attributes*? Yes, it can auto complete tags, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer on whether or not there is a plugin or option to enable completion for attributes akin to Dreamweaver's style.

This is in Dreamweaver:

[image]

And this is in NetBeans:

[image]

Can NetBeans mimic this feature through a plugin or an obscure option I can't seem to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new file of type "HTML" (using file->new file, type->other->html), the attributes will be suggested when you open, say a "" tab. This, I assume, is what you are looking for (me too!). However, I have noticed that you do not get the same if you create a "php web page", 
Sorry this does not completely answer the question but it may point you in the right directon. Netbeans needs to be configured to apply the same intellisense dictionary to a php web page (and whatever type of webpage you are editing) that it applies to a html type page

Comment: This was helpful. I noticed NetBeans will automatically declare an html doctype when you create a new HTML file -- I tried that in php: If you declare an HTML doctype in any php file that is included in your project, these hints will start to appear.

I guess `<!doctype html>` (and its equivalents) is what NetBeans uses to determine what type of hints to display.

Answer (score 1):

You you will get the list of attributes by clicking Ctr+space in php file